more of an all-at-once glance
SEO tools are incredibly useful, but you must understand how to use them to get the most out of them.
There are even a few toolsets that can help you in more than the areas we just mentioned, giving you more of an all-at-once glance at your SEO performance.
Can you help what ''more of an'' means?

Have you looked up any of the words in a dictionary? "An" is an indefinite article, "more" means what it usually does. Would you understand "He gave me more of the cake"?
